# JavaScript, Node

Tags: node.js, azure, oauth, passport.js

I am writing Oauth using Exchange client. I have registered my app at apps.dev.microsoft.com. I am using JavaScript with Node.js. To perform the Oauth, I have used passport with several different strategies, but none of them seem to work for me. Some of them were missing profile information, and this last one I am using does not return me the access token. I have debugged the lib, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Here is the lib I am using:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-node-webapp-openidconnect.
I am using the OIDC strategy.
So this returns a profile obj but access and refresh token is "undefined".It does return a authorization 'code' to make the token request. Redirect url, and all other meta data is fine such as:
  prompt: 'login',
  response_mode: 'query',
  state: true,
  authorizationURL: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
  tokenURL: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token'

Also, client ID , client secret and callbackURL are correct.

Did I miss something essential in the process or MSFT oauth with passport is broken?

Comment: Why did this guy get a down vote for this? Looks like a good question to me.

Answer (score 0):

As passport SDK doesn’t store `accessToken` and `refreshToken` in `user profile`. So we can modified sdk file to get tokens.

We can find these code in `node_modules/passport-azure-ad/lib/passport-azure-ad/oidcstrategy.js` begin in line `176` :

        `log.info('TOKEN RECEIVED');
        log.info('Access Token: ' + accessToken);
        log.info('');
        log.info('Refresh Token: ' + refreshToken);
        log.info('');
        log.info(params);
        log.info('----');`

And we can find `profile` is defined in line `229` and `265`. for easy use, we can directly add the tokens in the `profile`, for example, below code `var profile = {};` we add `profile.accessToken = accessToken;`.